# How can I read my db files on my device, without using a computer

Tags: android, sqlite, root, runas

I am just starting out developing on android and currently only code directly on my devices (both galaxy nexus and nexus 7) using the amazing app AIDE.

Looking on here there are lots of answers for pulling the DB onto your computer using adb, but I'm not using a computer.

I am seeing answers on building the app in debuggable mode and using 'run-as' but I get a no permission error. I don't have root and am not totally averse to putting it on but want to make sure there are no non-root ways to do this.

I'm trying the run-as stuff using connectbot.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can search on PlayStore : [SQLite Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager&feature=search_result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't have root and am not totally averse to putting it on but want to make sure there are no non-root ways to do this.

There are no non-root ways to do this without work on your end. One app (say, AIDE) has no rights to access the internal storage of another app (say, yours).

Non-root options include:

- Adding a backup feature to your app that copies the database to external storage, at which point you can use apps like the aSQLiteManager mentioned in the previous post (also available [directly on the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.andsen.asqlitemanager&feature=search_result)).
- Baking in some sort of SQLite editor into your app temporarily during development, removing it when you go to production.

Comment: Unfortunately at the moment, I am still just going through very basic tutorials. Some of which do db stuff. So I am not at a level in which I can add/bake in debug or features to view the db myself or dump them. I think root will be the way to go. I will be able to then use aSQLiteManager to look through the data folder, right? Or will the db made by my app still be off limits to other 'users' even root?

Comment: Do you know about the run-as feature? It sounds like a possible non root option...possibly!

Comment: @RussWheeler: Copying a file to external storage may be simpler than getting root access, and it is a feature for your users as well. That being said, you are welcome to try the root option. "I will be able to then use aSQLiteManager to look through the data folder, right? " -- yes, and the Play Store description makes it seem like aSQLiteManager makes that comparatively easy. "Do you know about the run-as feature?" -- the only "feature" like that of which I am aware involves a development PC, which for some reason you are eschewing.

Comment: I'm not eschewing the dev pc as such, but this is, at the moment, more just a hobby and I find most of my spare time is either travelling or when I am away from my computer/home. Its not a feature that I will want in my final app, just a way of helping me debug as I go. The run-as feature is something I've seen where you can run as the app/app user itself, and hence have access to bits without the need for root. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Tools like http://sourceforge.net/projects/asqlitemanager/ can read and write to local sql files locating on the sd card. (Without rooting the phone)
On rooted phone, lot of applications can read/write even to system DBs.

**I would suggest not to put any important data on local DB without encrypting it first**

---

Edit:
If I understand correctly, you have an SQLite application and you want to access **your** sqlite DB from outside of your application (but on your device)

If this is the case, I would try to have a "secret" option on my application (for debug version only) that will start an activity from `external sqlite browser application`.
Or you can have activity that copy your DB to a folder on the SD card, where you will be able to edit it easily
But what is that you **really need**?
Do you need to see the values only?
Do you need to check the structure?
Do you need full edit over the DB?
You might be able just to have a dump (writing to txt file on the SD card) the data without dealing with a full sqlite editor (based on your answer to those questions)

Comment: I have an sqlite app, but it can't read the db created by my app (sorry maybe I didn't explain that my app creates the db)

Comment: Re: your edit/update. What I need it for is to just track data is going in correctly, maybe to empty rows etc. I'd say general db stuff but at this stage mainly just to check the correct data is being stored. As I say in another reply, I'm far too novice to start adding features to dump or display the data. But what does your secret option do exactly? If you don't know about the run as function I think I'll just have to root it.

Comment: @RussWheeler, you can write the info you need to a file on your sd card. it should be an easy task... By "secret" I meant - "hidden from your users". but if you don't know how to start external application activity, just ignore it. Anyway, for your requirement, a simple output file should be enough

Comment: I can write certain values to a file, but I want to check that I'm writing to the database correctly. It's not the actual data I want to see, but whether it's going in properly or not.

Comment: @RussWheeler, So you **write to the DB**, then you **read from the DB** and write to a file. This way you can make sure the write works well

Comment: hmm yeah I guess. Still a bit annoying when you should just be able to look at the contents. Thanks